# EF6 - Adding new entities which belong to an already persisted entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Suppose I have a Company with a list of Employees:

```
public class Company
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Company CompanyOfWork { get; set; }
}
```

My Company already exists in the DB, but I need to save some **new** Employees.

Currently I would loop through the list of Employees, looking for new ones which need saving to the DB (in my case, ID = 0), and add them:

```
foreach(var employee in company.Employees)
{
    if(employee.ID == 0)
        db.Employees.Add(employee);
}
```

This creates the new Employees in the DB, but it also creates a duplicated record of the Company in the DB (presumably because EF looks at CompanyOfWork on Employee, and assumes it needs adding to the DB?)

What is the correct way to do this to prevent it from creating duplicates?

Do I need to first check if company already exists, and attach it if so? None of my suggestions feel very clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the employees to the existing company, then save the company, instead of adding them directly to the DbSet:

```
var existingCompany = db.Companies.Find(companyId);
foreach (var employee in employeesToAdd) {
    if (! existingCompany.Employees.Contains(employee)) {
        existingCompany.Employees.Add(employee);
    }
    else  {
        // update existing employee ...
    }
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

EF ChangeTracker will know that it also has to update the references between company and employee, if the relationship is modeled correctly for the persistable entities. This code also assumes that lazy loading of employees is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for this. Does this mean that when you have a very complex object you need to: go through all the entities, check whether they exist - if not then add them, if they do, mark as updated. If they're new and belong to a parent, Find() the parent in the DB and then add them. I'm just very surprised how awkward saving a complex object, is there a concrete sample somewhere of how it's done neatly?

Comment: Well you only have to check whether you must add, update or remove; the ChangeTracker will mark an entity as dirty automatically if you update it. At my company we move this check to another layer by providing explicit endpoints for Create, Update and Delete. You only have to add it to the parent if you want to create the relationship between parent and child.  If the relationship already exists, you can fetch the employee directly by its id, update it and all will be good. For stand alone entities you just add them directly to the DbSet as you have done in the original post.

Comment: Upon further testing we've actually realised the Find() approach doesn't throw errors - but also doesn't add anything to the database. It does add to the database if we include "db.Entry(employee) = EntityState.Added", but this produces the duplicates again. Any ideas if there's something simple we're missing? (I'm using the exact approach as above)

Comment: Hm is the relationship between Company and Employee modeled correctly? Something like `ModelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(c => c.Employees).WithRequired(e => e.CompanyOfWork ).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);`

Comment: Ah is this specifically for Code First approaches? We've taken the DB First approach.

Comment: I do not think Code First or DB First makes a difference, as long as the FK relations are correct. Also, if you do not have lazy loading enabled, you might need to include the Employees when retrieving the Company: `var existingCompany = db.Companies.Include(c => c.Employees).Single(c => c.Id == companyId);`